# ruby regex to match @variables{whatever, text, numbers, hex - not important}

Tags: ruby, regex

Im looking for a ruby regex to match this

@variables{
  color1 | #FFFFFF | links;
  color2 | #c1dfee | frame;
}

however - what is inside the braces is not important. I just want to capture that @variables{} with its content. So I guess Im looking for something like /@variables{MATCH-ANYTHING}/m

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
@variables\{[^}]*}
```

`[^}]` matches any character except `}`.

Comment: No problem. (15 chars minimum)

Answer (score 1):

how about `/@variables\{[^}]*\}/`

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
/@variables\{(.+)\}/.match("@variables{ color1 | #FFFFFF | links; color2 | #c1dfee | frame; }")[1]
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively: `/@variables\{.*?}/` to match anything between braces non-greedily

```
s = "foo{bar} @variables{blah blah} asdf{zxbc}"
s.match(/@variables\{(.*?)}/)
# => #<MatchData "@variables{blah blah}" 1:"blah blah">
```